# Synergy: crossing at any point along a non-continuous edge for a non-rectangular arrangement of dissimilar resolution displays on a mac?

Tags: mac, synergy

I have two displays of differing size (1920x1200 + 2560x1440) connected to two machines via a KVM each, but for the purposes of this question they can be treated as duplicate hardware (four displays). The mac is "above" the win7, like so:

```
section: links
    mac:
        down = win7
    win7:
        up = mac
end
```

---

If I have the mac's displays arranged with a continuous bottom edge everything works as expected. Hitting the bottom edge of either display on the mac switches to the win7.

[image: Working Arrangement]

---

However if I re-arrange the displays on the mac to instead have a continuous top edge I can only switch to the win7 on the bottom edge of the lower-most display.

[image: Problem Arrangement]

---

How do I eliminate the "barrier"?

P.S. Not really happy with the title of this question, but couldn't think of anything plainer that actually described the issue.